# Loading class in application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey I am trying to list classes for Honeybadger to ignore. The following code is used to ignore certain classes of errors:

config/initializers/honeybadger.rb:

```
config.before_notify do |notice|
    notice.halt! if config.honeybadger_error_exceptions.include?(notice.class)
  end
```

application.rb:

```
config.honeybadger_error_exceptions = [
      SomeModule::SomeCustomerError
    ]
```

however I get an uninitialized constant error (even when going into rails console). How can i make application.rb see that the class exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ignoring that class [using the configuration file](https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/ruby/getting-started/ignoring-errors/#ignore-by-class)?

Comment: That's the solution I chose. Thank you